# remove null characters from nsstring iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have this line of code that causes my app to crash.

```
 trimmedtext=[NSString stringWithCString:[mycharstring cStringUsingEncoding:[ NSString defaultCStringEncoding ] ] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The error is: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]: NULL cString'

It crashes because there are NULL chars i think in my NSString.

NSLog gives me this 'friendXx' , there is an emoticon in the string!

How can i overcome this issue?

Any help appreciated.

**Correct answer: text=[NSString stringWithCString:[mycharstring UTF8String ] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];**

Comment: Have you checked if your `mycharstring` is valid?

Comment: NSLog gives me this friendXx , there is an emoticon in the string!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Are you sure, that the `defaultCStringEncoding` returns the particular `NSStringEncoding` that you need in this case? Do you know the encoding of `mycharstring`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help all. H2CO3 was right the correct code is: text=[NSString stringWithCString:[mycharstring UTF8String ] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It crashes because there are NULL chars in my NSString.

Except that it doesn't.

The problem is that the C string (of type `const char *`) is a pointer of which the value is `NULL`, i. e. it's the invalid pointer. The principal reason of this may be, for example, that the `mycharstring` variable is `nil`.

Edit: so there's some symbol in the string that the default C string encoding can't handle, that's why it returns NULL. Try using `[mycharstring UTF8String]` instead.

Comment: NSLog gives me this 'friendXx' , there is an emoticon in the string!

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! this is the correct code:text=[NSString stringWithCString:[mycharstring UTF8String ] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];